# How do you read XML Data in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table which has XMLData column as TEXT. How can i read the data from this column

Comment: TSQL? C#? Lacking sufficient detail....

Comment: Why aren't you storing it as an XML datatype instead of Text? That would be step 1.

Comment: You won't really be able to do anything interesting with the text data type. One of the reasons it's been deprecated.

Comment: its already there.... can't change it. have to use it as it is... is there any way????

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourXmlColumn XML` and you're done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as that column is of type `TEXT`, you won't be able to do anything useful with it, really. `TEXT` also has been deprecated and [will be removed in a future version of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) - stop using it.

If it stores XML and only XML - make it of datatype `XML`.

One you have that, you can either extract individual items of information from that XML using XPath and XQuery - something like:

```
SELECT
    YourXMlColumn.value('(/Root/SomeItems/Item/FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'FirstName',
    YourXMlColumn.value('(/Root/SomeItems/Item/Age)[1]', 'int') as 'Age'
FROM
    dbo.YourTable
WHERE
    (some condition)
```

or if you have multiple items in a list-like structure inside your XML, you can create a "pseudo-table" of XML items based on an XPath expression.

So your plan of action should be:

1. make this column use the appropriate datatype - `XML`
2. tell us in more detail what kind of XML you have stored in there, and what you want to get from that XML

Comment: THanks for your quick reply. Will change the datatype to XML

Answer (score 0):

Make your column an XML datatype instead of TEXT. The following MSDN article is a lengthy description of how XML is supported in sql server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(v=sql.90).aspx